# Why won't Pik install Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pik

After a failure trying to install Ruby on Rails from here: http://railsinstaller.org/, I am now trying to install things manually.

I thought I would install Pik first and then hit "pik install ruby" from the command prompt.  Seemingly, nothing could be simpler than that. However, I am receiving the message "Ruby not found". How could this be?

Comment: Have you set `pik` in your environment variables?

Comment: The installation mentioned that it added pik to my Path.  Anyways, do you mean adding pik to my path (in some other way) or setting up a new environmental variable or changing "home" or something?  How would I do that...exactly?

Comment: In the docs it says: `If you install pik using the msi you must set the ‘HOME’ or ‘PIK_HOME’ environment variable to the directory pik installs to, ususally the path specified in %USERPROFILE%.`

Comment: @sawa ever figure this out? The pik msi added c:\pik to the system PATH variable for me but I went ahead and added PIK_HOME to my user variables and this changes nothing. Which makes sense because the system is not having an issue finding pik. It is saying it can't find Ruby which doesn't exist at this point. You are correct that the install instructions imply you can run pik install to install your first ruby but I believe you have to actually have a version of ruby installed already for this. Which makes it silly to install pik on a system that doesn't have ruby installed

Answer (score 1):

While the `pik` gem is no longer maintained, `pik` from [here](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) is still the best way to manage multiple ruby versions on windows. (Please someone write another one. Or talk Gordon Thiesfeld into letting someone else manage it.)

Setting up `pik` is painful (you are require to manually install the ruby versions, the required `devkit`s and then tell `pik` to use them).

If you don't need multiple, ruby versions, I recommend you use the excellent installers from [here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) and use `gem install rails` to get your windows, ruby on rails fix.

Answer (score 0):

it seems Pik cannot install Ruby automatically. It's just manager of ruby versions. In order to install Ruby on Windows it's necessary to use RubyInstaller for Windows http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and then pik add C:\Ruby193\bin (or any other path to installed ruby)